# How to find changes on Gitlab that we did not upload (git push), just added (git add) and commented?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, version-control, gitlab

I am developing an application on React Native in Visual Studio code, When to upload work to Git I followed like this:

1. Stage all changes
2. commit
   And then the computer shuts down and I can no longer turn it on. I did not have enough time to do it(Push). I have now downloaded my app to another computer. Is it possible to somehow restore these changes?
   Or via the "Visual Studio Code", Or maybe there may be cache left somewhere,Or another way?

Answer (score 1):

All the unpushed changes are kept in the `.git` directory, unless you have access to that, I'm afraid there isn't a way.